# How can I explicitly write an array reference return type?

Tags: c++, syntax

I want to know how to explicitly the return type of a function that returns a reference to an array.

```
typedef int const (Three_Const_Ints)[3];

Three_Const_Ints const & foo ()
{
    static int const values[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
    return values;
}

int const (&)[3] bar ()   // Does not compile. What is the proper syntax?
{
    static int const values[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
    return values;
}
```

Yes, I can use `std::array`, but I would like to know this syntax for the hell of it.

Answer (score 1):

It goes like this:

```c++
int const (&bar())[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

to return a reference to an array use this syntax:

```
int const (& bar())[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
int const (& bar() )[3]
{
    static int const values[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
    return values;
}
```

Or

```
typedef const int Three_Const_Ints[3];

Three_Const_Ints & f()
{
    static Three_Const_Ints values = { 0, 1, 2 };
    return values;
}
```